# How to handle double monitors in ObjectiveC?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cordova

I'm working with a Cordova Mac application and I can see weird behaviours when I have more than one monitor plugged in.

I'm using a Point to center the view which is on the Icon on the Menubar. However, when I work with two monitors, you have to click several times to actually get the right position.

This is the code to show the window:

```
- (void) showPanel
{
    NSRect statusFrame = [[self.statusItem valueForKey:@"window"] frame];
    NSRect winFrame = [self.window frame];
    NSRect screenFrame = [[self.window screen] frame];

    NSPoint p = NSMakePoint(statusFrame.origin.x, screenFrame.size.height - 32);
    if (p.x > (screenFrame.size.width - winFrame.size.width)) {
        p.x = screenFrame.size.width - winFrame.size.width - 30;
    }

    [self.window setFrameTopLeftPoint:p];
    [self.window setIsVisible:YES];
    [NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
    [self.window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
}
```

I'm a total newbie when it comes to ObjectiveC so I'm not sure is there any considerations I should have in mind for this kind of scenarios.

Comment: What's **Cordova**???

Comment: The open source version of **Phonegap**